# Creating an Umbraco widget that contains JavaScript

Tags: javascript, umbraco

What I am trying to do is create a sidebar widget that contains some JavaScript that generates some dynamic content. Using third party libraries is not an option.

I have created the widget (and underlying template), made sure it can be published, added the widget to the relevant page.

*start of edit*

[image]

In the image above the widget is to go under the "New Lower Prices" widget. I.e. Column 2 of this 3 column layout.

*end of edit*

I am using Umbraco 7.5.3

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're going to give a bit more information, it's not clear what your actual issue is? It sounds like you've created a sidebar widget already?

Comment: I have updated my question with a screen shot

Comment: Still not clear after your edit. What's the problem? Where is your code?

Comment: The problem is that the widget is not appearing.

Comment: Great, we have the problem statement; yet without accompanying code/information on _how_ you are doing this, it's nearly impossible to help you debug.

Comment: I was adding the steps I took, and as I was going through them I noticed something, sorry for the poor question...... If I am still having the problem/resolved the issue, I will update this post accordingly

Comment: It's ok, just trying to help you out to get the help you need :)

Comment: No worries, I appreciate it. Made me look in detail rather than glancing.....

Comment: For those wondering I figured it out by accident, though whilst moving it to UAT I broke it..... Arrgggghhhh..

Answer (score 0):

I now remember what the issue was.... The underlying model for the widget **did not** match the definition of the template. By syncing up the C# model with the template the widget appeared.

[Edit]

Additionally the cshtml code file must match the name of the template (other than case - unless, I guess, you have the files on a case sensitive file system).